# Can I assign the value to viewbag element in View and use it in controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am developing the MVC app.

I pass the value from controller to view using viewbag , in View I make some changes in the data which comes from the viewbag.
After completion the changes, I want to send that changed data back to the controller.

So I have a query , Can I assign the values to ViewBag elements in View and these values can I use in controller ?

( data travels from , Controller -> View - > Controller)

Comment: If the view is making modifications to the data you are doing something seriously wrong.

Comment: You are ignoring the "M" (Model) in "MVC". Instead of saying that your requirements are different (they are not), please take a look at mattytommo's answer and give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You should **really** use the Model to do things like that. That's one the things it's there for! Plus it's best practice.

Consider this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then here's your `HttpGet` action:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyAction()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@model MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Value)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Value)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Then your `HttpPost` action would be:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    //model.Value is the value you typed in
}
```

**EDIT: As suggested in comments, here's how you can do it for a drop down list value:**

Given this model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Selections { get; set; }
}
```

You can populate it in your `HttpGet` like:

```
[HttpGet]
public MyAction()
{
    MyModel model = new MyModel();

    model.Selections = db.Values //replace with your db table
        .Select(v => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = v.Name //value to go in your text field
                Value = v.Id.ToString() //value to go in your ID field
            })
        .ToList();   

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view you can do:

```
@model MyModel

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SelectedId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.Selections)
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Then here's your `HttpPost`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    //model.SelectedId is the value you selected
}
```

Comment: well, I have a the case like, I have a drop down the item which selected in drop down its first two character should saved in DB, so I have to pass data from View to controller. I am quit confused how to do that ?

Comment: Negative, My problem is lets say I have country dropdown, If I selected United States, the I will Send US, If I selected India I will send the 2 chars, as IN , means I can send any chars.so I want to know the simpler way . to pass data to controller.

Comment: @user1650894 Do you store that short hand value in your database? If so you can set the `Value` field of the `SelectListItem` to be that. Using the model is both the simplest and best practice way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really what the `ViewBag` is designed for - it's all in the name really, it should only contain *view-specific* data used to pass information **from** the controller to the view (not the other way about).

The preferred way of passing information from a view to a controller is via `POST` request to a particular action.

Comment: well, I have a the case like, I have a drop down the item which selected in drop down its first two character should saved in DB, so I have to pass data from View to controller. I am quit confused how to do that ?

Comment: @user1650894 the `ViewBag` dictionary does not persist between postbacks so, like I said, if you need information from your view passed to your controller you need to `POST` this back. There are plenty of examples on here, @mattytommo's is as good as any.

Answer (score 0):

You could but it would not be best practice to do so.  The view is primarily there to display content to the user, any changes the user makes should be sent back to the controller and processed in your ViewModel.

`ViewBag` is primarily used to pass data from the controller to the view, not vice versa.

From your comments:

Check out this entry which will help you understand how to pass data back up to the controller and update the database:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx

Comment: well, I have a the case like, I have a drop down the item which selected in drop down its first two character should saved in DB, so I have to pass data from View to controller. I am quit confused how to do that ?

Comment: @user1650894 - you need a model which is sent down to the view behind the scenes (like @mattytommo has shown) - you then pass the changed data back up to the controller via a `HTTP POST` and save it in your database, either in the controller of view model.

Comment: @user1650894 - I have included a link in my answer to help you understand how to achieve this.

Comment: Not getting, My req. is quit different... I just want to pass 2 characters to Controller from view, these two characters are total different, they are nothing to do with any property , is there any easy way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know,Answer is No. `ViewBag` can be processed only on server side.
ViewBag cannot be used to send data back to the controller from a rendered view. As a view is processed by a view engine (server side),then it is rendered to html which is send to the browser(client).
Now your selection is made on client side not server side. So you need to write some javascripts (client side code) and send the changes back to the server.